# cannot run 'from causalml.inference.tree import UpliftTreeClassifier, UpliftRandomForestClassifier'

Tags: scikit-learn, causalml

Hey I am using causalml package. but I cannot load

```
from causalml.inference.tree import UpliftTreeClassifier, UpliftRandomForestClassifier
```

or this line

```
from causalml.dataset import make_uplift_classification
```

The error I got was the same

```
ValueError: sklearn.tree._tree.TreeBuilder size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 80 from C header, got 72 from PyObject
```

Can someone advise? I am working on a uplift modeling project. It seems casualml is kind of lack of maintain, any other packages to recommend?

thank you very much